# How to match text in [...] with NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, regex

what would be the NSRegularExpression to match the text between the "[" and the "]" in the following example:

"[this is some] text i would [like] to [parse] with NSRegularExpression"

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about NSRegularExpression, but I suspect it's like other regular expressions in terms of greediness. So, if there could be multiple [words] or [phrases in brackets] that you want to capture in the same string, you'll have to make sure the regex isn't greedy.

Maybe something like (broken up across a few lines for clarity:)

```
\[                     // find an opening square bracket
  ([^]]+)              // find one or more characters that ARE NOT a square bracket
\]                     // find the corresponding closing square bracket
```

Comment: so what would be the regex to find the text not included in brackets ?

Answer (score 2):

Like a Daniel answer right pattern is `\\[(.*?)\\]`
Let me explain why.

1. `\\[` is mean "open-bracket" symbol. Double slash allow to use special symbol `[`
2. All in `( )` allow to union as atomic sequence
3. `.` — any symbol without special `* ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /!`
4. `*?` — symbol entry 0 or more times. Match as few times as possible.
5. `\\]` — close-bracket

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should be `\[(.*?)\]`

Comment: Regex matching is generally greedy, so most implementations would match this as "this is some] text i would [like] to [parse" based on the OP's input text. You need to explicitly disallow closing braces.